# Which is processed better for arrays?

Tags: php, process, foreach, while-loop

although i use foreach and while,

i was wondering if using the `for(i=0;i<varlength;i++)` will have some difference, how does php process for() and foreach() differently?

Comment: For benchmarks: http://www.phpbench.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loops are a bit faster, but consider the following:

```
$bar = array("cow"=>"moo", "cat"=>"meaw", "dog"=>"barf");
foreach($bar as $key => $value){
 echo "The ".$key." goes ".$value.".<br>";
}
```

- With foreach you have easier access the the values as well as the key values.  This becomes easier and more apparent with associative array operations.
- foreach is a bit easier to read    and maintain.

Comment: This is not related to `for` or `foreach`. Don't use double quotations if you simply initialize strings, because PHP searches for variables inside double quoted strings adding more processing. `"The ".$key." goes ".$value.".<br>"` could be rewritten as `"The {$key} goes {$value}.<br>"` (using variable interpolation) or `'The ' . $key . ' goes ' . $value . '.<br>'` (using concatenation).

Comment: @Amil: see the link RobertPitt posted under the question for a practical example of how it is wrong.

Comment: @Amil - How is it not related to `for` or `foreach`? Could you write my example using for so i could see the difference.  Although you have a point about interpolation and concatenation, they weren't the focus of my example :)

Answer (score 2):

If there's any difference in performance it's probably negligible. I'd stick with `foreach` since it's more clear you're doing iteration over an array here (foreach is used for iterating over Iterator implementing classes as well)

Comment: apparently the difference is 276% roughly, according to phpbench (see link in comment from robert). Not negligible but in most instances probably meaningless. The for loop is faster - if you're looping a few thousand things, who cares, but if you're looping 500,000 it may matter.

Comment: See all tests on this page. Depending on what you do for() can be slower by as much than foreach(). Given that the slowest part of an average PHP is communication with external data sources (a database in most cases) I still call that negligible.